# Editing code in a template page with own theme in magento 1.6 

Tags: php, templates, magento, themes

I have created a copy of the blank template and inserted 2 parts of it at:

```
app\design\frontend\default\mytheme\
```

and

```
htdocs\skin\frontend\default\mytheme\
```

Then I inserted the theme name in the magento backend:

---

[image]

---

This works so far and I can make changes to the files that are below these 2 locations and they show up in the frontend.

The next thing is, I want to make some changes in the template file which is originally at

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\2columns-left.phtml
```

Because I want to incorporate the change into my theme and of course not modify the base tree, I made a copy (please excuse some slashes are the wrong direction, in my environment I use them correctly):

```
cd app\design\frontend\default\mytheme\
mkdir template
cd template
mkdir page
```

Now I create a copy into this directory of the template file that I just mentioned and it becomes `app\design\frontend\default\mytheme\template\page\2columns-right.phtml`.

As soon as I make the copy, the magento shop frontend only displays an empty page. I have to delete thecopy and the shop works again.

When I make my change in the original file `2columns-right.phtml` it shows up in the frontend, but I want to incorporate it in my theme, not change the base tree.

How do I do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are copying it over correctly. If it's displaying an empty page when you create the copy of 2columns-right.phtml it could be caused by php errors in the template, or incorrect file permissions on 2columns-right.phtml

Comment: thank you, i will try. it could be permissions, because after the copy process (without any changes) the error occurs